# Does API version matter when creating custom classes/triggers?

Tags: apex, api

I noticed you can choose/change which version of the Salesforce.com API when you create a class or trigger. Are there are benefits to using a new or older version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Selecting a newer version will generally give you access to additional features, since the functionality available to your code is tied to the API version. To take a somewhat random example, the `IsPartner` field on `Account` can be updated in API version 16.0 and later. If you selected API version 15.0 or earlier for your code, `IsPartner` would be read-only.

The version number is there so your code doesn't break as Salesforce introduces new goodies. I can't think of a reason that you would pick an older version for new code, unless you're extending an existing system.